# a quick question on a product of two algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $P$ be a rational polynomial of degree $n$ with roots $z_1,\dots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Is it true that any product of two of the numbers $z_1,\dots,z_n$ is also a root of rational polynomial of degree at most $n$?

Comment: What is $P$? Is $P$ a number field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=5$ for the polynomial $P (z)=(z^3-2)(z^2-2)$, and $z_1=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $z_2=\sqrt{2}$. Then the minimal polynomial for $z_1z_2=\sqrt[6]{32}$ is $z^6-32$.

Comment: I think $n = 6$ in this case since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$.

Comment: Its the case $n=5$ with $P=(x^2-2)(x^3-2)$.

Comment: @MooS You're right. Do you want to edit the answer?

Comment: I wonder if there is an example where $P$ is irreducible

Comment: Yes there is. Take any quartic with galois group equal to $S_4$. Then for two roots $a,b$, their product is fixed by the subgroup generated by $(12),(34)$ which is the Klein four group, hence $[\mathbb Q(ab):\mathbb Q]=24/4=6$

Comment: Yes @MooS, and surely generically $z_i z_j$ satisfies an irreducible of degree $n(n-1)/2$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Galois theory. MooS, could you write some more details as an answer? And an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your not familiar with Galois theory, you will not understand the answer. It is very hard to give an explicit example (i.e. writing down the roots), since it is very hard to write down the roots of a generic quartic. And for quintics this is of course well known to be impossible. Galois theory guarantees me the existence of such an example, I am not willing to write one down :)

Comment: @MooS Do I fill in the details correctly? Firstly, $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d) / \mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, so $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d) / \mathbb{Q}(ab)$ is Galois too. Now $ab$ is fixed by $(a b)$ and $(c d)$, but not the other transpositions. So $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d) / \mathbb{Q}(ab)) = <(a b), (c d)>$ which is the Klein-4 group. Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d) : \mathbb{Q}(ab)] = 4$. By tower law, we are done.